# Can I configure a logger for a trait separately from logger of the class implementing the trait

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

My `play` application has a Component defined as as `trait` as follows: It is the interface to database connection.

```
trait CassandraRepositoryComponents {
  def environment: Environment
  def configuration: Configuration
  def applicationLifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle
  val utilities:HelperMethods 
  val cassandraConnectionService = CassandraConnectionManagementService()

  val myLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)
...
}
```

The `AppComponent` classes implements the trait.

```
class AppComponents (context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
  with CassandraRepositoryComponents /
..
}
```

Is is possible to control logging for `AppComponent` and `CassandraRepositoryComponents` separately. At the moment, the `CassandraRepositoryComponents` takes logging configuration of `AppComponent` maybe because the main class is `AppComponent`. So the code `val myLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)` gets `AppComponent` class name? How can I do this? May be I need to change `CassandraRepositoryComponents` from being a `trait` to something else. What could that be?

UPDATE
I tried to provide a harded-coded name to `CassandraRepositoryComponents`

```
val cassandraRepositoryComponentsLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("CassandraRepositoryComponents")
```

But I am not seeing the logging even when all levels are enabled in `logback.xml`.

```
  <logger name="cassandraRepositoryComponentsLogger" level="ALL" additivity="false"> <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/> </logger>
```

In one of the methods of `CassandraRepositoryComponents`, I am using the logger and `println` but I can see only `println` message.

```
println(s"database will connect with keyspace ${keyspaceName}") //SHOWS
    cassandraRepositoryComponentsLogger.debug(s"debugger - database will connect with keyspace ${keyspaceName}") //DOESN'T SHOW
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the same name in `LoggerFactory.getLogger(...)` and in `<logger name="..."`.

Comment: Thanks. Just found it and was about to update the question. Silly me! It should have been `<logger name="cassandraRepositoryComponents" level="ALL" additivity="false"> <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/> </logger>`